# How to set default value for string in attributes at declare-styleable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm setting some attributes with declare-styleable to make a custom view. One of this attributes is a string. What I want to do, is that if I dont set a value in XML for thiks attribute, give it a default value but I don't know how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name ="MyCustomView">
     <attr name ="title" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In my custom view Im doing this:

```
private var title = ""
init{
  val styledAttr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.MyCustomView)
  title = styledAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_title)!! //I cant remove "!!" or I get a type mismatch Required String Found String?

  myTextView.text = title
}
```

In some XML:

```
<!--Here I can set title attribute but I want that if I dont set it a value, set a default value-->
<com.example.myproject.MyCustomView
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: `title = styledAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_title) ?: "Default Title"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I cant remove "!!" or I get a type mismatch Required String Found String?
title = styledAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_title)!!
```

The type mismatch is because you're doing this:

```
private var title = ""
```

You're creating a `var` without specifying its *type*, so the compiler needs to *infer* it from the value you're assigning. Because you're assigning a `String`, it ends up being this:

```
private var title: String = ""
```

which is a *non-null* type - the compiler can't (and shouldn't!) assume you want it to be nullable just by passing a `String`, so you have to specify the type explicitly:

```
private var title: String? = ""
//  note the nullable ? ^^^
```

Now you're still assigning a non-null `String`, but you *can* set `title` to *null* if you want. So you don't need the `!!` (which you should avoid using unless you know there's a very good reason to - you're not fixing the problem you've created, just hiding it until it goes wrong)

---

That's just a general explanation for that error you're getting, so you know what it's about and how to deal with it - the actual solution to your problem is what DarShan posted in the comments:

```
title = styledAttr.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_title) ?: "Default Title"
```

`styledAttr#getString` will return *null* if the `styleable` reference you're looking up doesn't exist on that `attr` - which is good, because it means you get a "nothing there" result you can check for. If the result is *null*, then provide a default fallback value instead

Which is what the [elvis operator (`?:`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) is doing in that line - set `title` to the result of `getString`, **unless that's null**, in which case evaluate the stuff after the elvis and use that value instead. So `title` either gets assigned a `String` from `getString`, or `"Default Title"` which is also a `String`. Either way, it's not going to be null, so `title` can stay as the non-null `String` type instead of needing to be changed to `String?` (never use a nullable type unless you *need* null values)

You could assign the result of `getString` to a temp variable and do `title = if (tempString != null) tempString else "DefaultTitle"` but hopefully you can see how Kotlin makes it pretty elegant with its null-handling stuff. That's why nulls show up a lot in Kotlin as a kind of nothing/failure value, so you can easily handle those cases and provide fallbacks